# Trying to recover a deleted encrypted partition

Tags: ubuntu, luks

I have deleted the root partition on my ubuntu box. The partition was encrypted with LUKS

So far I have managed to find the partition and decrypt it

with

```
losetup -o 0xXXXXXXXX -r -f /dev/sda

losetup -a

cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop8 luksrecover
```

I can seen the device in

`/dev/mapper/luksrecover`

under `lsblk`:

```
loop8 (loop)

--luksrecover (crypt)

----vgubuntu-root (lvm)

----vgubuntu-swap_1 (lvm)
```

but if I try to mount it I get `/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root already mounted or mount point busy`.

I cannot find it mounted anywhere when I type mount.

I feel so close yet so far. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this steps help you.

1. Use `losetup  -a`  to see the Mount point of the loop 8.
2. if there try `umount /«Mount point»`.
3. then Mount it again using `mount /dev/mapper/luksrecover  /`

Comment: no mount point. When I try mounting /dev/mapper/luksrecover I get unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member.  Today when I try mounting /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root, I get con't read superblock on /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root. If possible I would like to rewrite the partition table as it was and re-point the GRUB entry to boot where it used to.